# Why does detectMultiScale detect faces only when they are close to the centre of the frame?

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection

I am trying a very simple program to detect faces in a webcam feed. I am noticing that the faces are detected well when my face is in the centre of the frame. Whenver I move a bit to the sides, the face detector either completely misses my face or gives no detection. 
Is this bias because of the way I am using the function (code appended) or is it an inherent bias in the HAAR Classifiers? 
Note that in either case (my face being in the approximate centre of the frame or my face being somewhere near the boundaries), my face is completely visible, i.e so side profiles/or cutting of the face.

```
//A live face detector Program. Takes feed from the camera and detects face in the given frame

#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include"opencv2/video/video.hpp"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;



 int main(){
     cv::Mat frame;
     cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
     cv::namedWindow("Frame");
 do{
        cap >> frame;

        Rect r1,r2;
        vector<Rect> faces1,faces2;
        CascadeClassifier cascade1;
        CascadeClassifier cascade2;
        //cascade1.load("C:/opencv2.4.9/sources/data/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");
        cascade1.load("C:/opencv2.4.9/sources/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");
        cascade2.load("C:/opencv2.4.9/sources/data/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_profileface.xml");
        cascade1.detectMultiScale(frame, faces1,1.05, 6, CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT, Size(0, 0));
        cascade2.detectMultiScale(frame, faces2,1.05, 6, CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT, Size(0, 0));
        if (faces1.size()!=0){
            cout << "face1 found";
            r1 = faces1[0];
        }

        if (faces2.size()!=0){
            cout << "face2 found";
            r2 = faces2[0];
        }

            rectangle(frame, Point(r1.y,r1.x), Point(r1.y+r1.height,r1.x+r1.width), Scalar(0,255,0),2, 8);
            rectangle(frame, Point(r2.y,r2.x), Point(r2.y+r2.height,r2.x+r2.width), Scalar(255,0,0),2, 8);
            imshow("Frame",frame);
        }while(waitKey(30) < 0);

 cap.release();
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I would suggest its something to do with your training size, always train as small as possible. If you trained on Images that were large you wont be able to detect smaller  (or further away) faces

Comment: I am using the xml files packaged with openCV. I haven't trained on anything. This code is just to detect a face. No recognition.

Comment: In the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html) they find faces that are not in the center. But they are using "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml".

Comment: Does your method find only one face or it can find more provided that they are in the center of the frame?

Comment: @powder: The code I have written is such that it will always give only one detection.

Comment: @Theolodies: I tried that xml also. I observe a similar pattern. The xml I am using seems to be working better(in terms of accuracy) in comparison though.

Comment: You could try to change xml file and see if results change. Consider though that it gets the bigger one, and it often is the one in the center of the frame due to projective deformation during acquisition..

Comment: I am sorry. This problem is solved. The detections were good. I was displaying them incorrectly. The co-ordinates were inverted. Which also explains why detections in the centre worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your haar classifier code is working well.in your code change this

```
 rectangle(frame, Point(r1.y,r1.x), Point(r1.y+r1.height,r1.x+r1.width), Scalar(0,255,0),2, 8);
        rectangle(frame, Point(r2.y,r2.x), Point(r2.y+r2.height,r2.x+r2.width), Scalar(255,0,0),2, 8);
```

to

```
rectangle(frame, Point(r1.x, r1.y), Point(r1.x + r1.width, r1.y + r1.height), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2, 8);
    rectangle(frame, Point(r2.x, r2.y), Point(r2.x + r2.width, r2.y + r2.height), Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2, 8);
```

it will work. you have changed the x,y values.